# How can I center text in a div?

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS and don't really understand this.

Before I was using `table`s and it was easy. Now I have 10 divs and each has a number inside. I want to get the numbers to all be in the center of the `div`s which are all same width.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Please - read a CSS tutorial for beginners, of which there are too many to count; then make an effort and try something out - and come back with questions...

Answer (score 7):

`text-align: center` 
should be enough

Comment: Yep, putting that on your body {} selector will make all text on the page center-aligned.

Answer (score 1):

I think that besides wanting them to be horizontally in the centre you also mean that they should be vertically in the centre (`middle` in CSS terminology). Have a look at this CSS sniplet and the JSFiddle with working example: http://jsfiddle.net/yc6s8/

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your css code just add

```
div#yourId
{
    text-align:center;
}
```

if you want to align a specific item in your div you could do the following. let's say this is your html

```
<div class="myDiv">
<p class="align">21</p>
<p>text goes here</p>
</div>
```

then in your css code

```
.align{text-align:center;}
```

this way you just need to add the class align to the element you want and it will be centered (but this will only work with block elements, the paragraph tag is a block element but for example the span tag is not)

Comment: With #div {} you select a <div id="div"> or any other element that has an id with value div. To select all <div> elements on the page use the css selector div {} without #.

Comment: it's an example, I have no idea what his html looks like or what his id or class of his div is named! that's no reason to downvote because even if it's a bit confusing it's still correct syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="test">12345</div>
```

And in your CSS:

```
.test{
    text-align: center;
}
```

Text-align can also take `left;` or `right;` to align to left and right.  If you want to center the div in it's container you would do:

```
.test
{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```